# what is this ambiguous behavior of RichEditBox while setting Link in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            box1 = new RichEditBox()
            {
                Width = 500,
                Height = 500,
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1)
            };
            btn = new Button() { Content = "button" };
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            string str = "ppppppavaniiiiipavanlllllpavankjhgfcdsa";
            box1.Document.SetText(0, str);
            box1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

            {
                ITextSelection selection1 = box1.Document.Selection;

                selection1.StartPosition = 5;
                selection1.EndPosition = 10;
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection1.StartPosition);
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection1.EndPosition);

                selection1.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On;

                string s = "\"google.com\"";
                selection1.Link = s;

                selection1.Collapse(false);
            }
            {
                ITextSelection selection2 = box1.Document.Selection;

                selection2.StartPosition = 25;
                selection2.EndPosition = 30;
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection2.StartPosition);
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection2.EndPosition);

                selection2.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On;
                selection2.CharacterFormat.Size = 20;
                selection2.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 50, 77, 98);
                selection2.CharacterFormat.Name = "Algerian";

                string s = "\"gjhgfdghje.com\"";
                selection2.Link = s;
            }

            grid.Children.Add(box1);
            grid.Children.Add(btn);
        }
```

After setting the `Link` for the range 5 to 10 before setting the Link and RichText for the range 25 to 30 which some how getting applied for the range 5 to 10 instead of 25 to 30.
here is the output [image]

If I move the second block of code above the first as below

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            box1 = new RichEditBox()
            {
                Width = 500,
                Height = 500,
                BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1)
            };
            btn = new Button() { Content = "button" };
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            string str = "ppppppavaniiiiipavanlllllpavankjhgfcdsa";
            box1.Document.SetText(0, str);
            box1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

            {
                ITextSelection selection2 = box1.Document.Selection;

                selection2.StartPosition = 25;
                selection2.EndPosition = 30;
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection2.StartPosition);
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection2.EndPosition);

                selection2.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On;
                selection2.CharacterFormat.Size = 20;
                selection2.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 50, 77, 98);
                selection2.CharacterFormat.Name = "Algerian";

                string s = "\"gjhgfdghje.com\"";
                selection2.Link = s;
            }
            {
                ITextSelection selection1 = box1.Document.Selection;

                selection1.StartPosition = 5;
                selection1.EndPosition = 10;
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection1.StartPosition);
                Debug.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" + selection1.EndPosition);

                selection1.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On;

                string s = "\"google.com\"";
                selection1.Link = s;

                selection1.Collapse(false);
            }
            grid.Children.Add(box1);
            grid.Children.Add(btn);
        }
```

then the output is this [image]

why is this behavior is like this.

Comment: After setting the `ITextRange.Link` Property, `ITextRange.EndPosition` will go to the end of the Text. This behavior has not been explained in the official document. According to the current behavior, please set the link in the order from the back to the front.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Then if we want to set the Link in runtime for the larger ranges after setting the Link for the lower ranges, it is not possible!

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT And how to remove the Link which has been set, how to extend or compress the range of the Link which has been set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally figured it out how RichEditBox is working while having links,
After applying link for this range

```
{
                ITextSelection selection1 = box1.Document.Selection;
                selection1.StartPosition = 5;
                selection1.EndPosition = 10;
                string s = "\"google.com\"";
                selection1.Link = s;
}
```

if we see the text of RichEditBox using `box1.TextDocument.GetText(0, out txt);` then it is in this format `pppppHYPERLINK "google.com"pavaniiiiipavanlllllpavankjhgfcdsa`,here the fixed characters are  `HYPERLINK` total 10 characters with space at the end, and we can get the link length from the

```
int prevlinklength;
{
                ITextSelection selection1 = box1.Document.Selection;
                selection1.StartPosition = 5;
                selection1.EndPosition = 10;
                prevlinklength = selection1.Link.length;
}

//now if we want to apply the link for the 25 to 30 range means 
{
                ITextSelection selection1 = box1.Document.Selection;
                selection1.StartPosition = 25 + 10 + prevlinklength;
                selection1.EndPosition = 30 + 10 + prevlinklength;
                string s = "\"google.com\"";
                selection1.Link = s;
}
```

now final text will be in this format

```
pppppHYPERLINK "google.com"pavaniiiiipavanlllllHYPERLINK "google.com"pavankjhgfcdsa
```